# C++ - Swap two objects *without* using an equals operator

Tags: c++

So I had a coding interview a week ago for an advanced C++ position where the question was basically asking me to swap two insantiations of a class called `Line`. Which is basically just a container for a `std::vector<int>`. But the assignment operator was private so I couldn't swap the variables normally. It also had a weirdly unimplemented function called "swap" that was just there. No implementation or anything. I have spent the past week going over the question in my head having no idea how to tackle this. I'm by no means a c++ expert, but I am also not a complete newbie. I however have not come up with anything useful. Was it asking me to subclass the `Line` class? Manipulate pointers? I have no clue.

Note that the **`main` and `Line` class were unmodifiable.

Here is the code I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Unmodifiable Code:
class Line {
    std::vector<int> people;
    void operator=(Line& other);
public:
    Line(std::vector<int> p) : people(p) {}
    
    void print_ids() {
        for (auto i = this->people.begin(); i != this->people.end(); ++i) {
            std::cout<<*i;
        }
    }
    
    void swap(Line& other);
};
// End Unmodifiable Code.

// THIS IS WHAT I HAD TO IMPLEMENT:
void switch_lines(Line& line1, Line& line2) {
    // TODO: This.
}

// Unmodifiable Code
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    std::vector<int> people1 = std::vector<int>();
    people1.push_back(12);
    people1.push_back(3);
    people1.push_back(4);
    people1.push_back(5);
     
    std::vector<int> people2 = std::vector<int>();
    people2.push_back(7);
    people2.push_back(8);
    people2.push_back(9);
    
    auto line1 = Line(people1);
    auto line2 = Line(people2);
    
    std::cout<<"The Lines Before:\n";
    line1.print_ids();
    line2.print_ids();
    
    switch_lines(line1, line2);
    
    std::cout<<"The Lines After:\n";
    line1.print_ids();
    line2.print_ids();
    
}
// End Unmodifiable Code.
```

Here is what I can think of and why it can't work:

- **Swapping the internal vectors:** doesn't work because the `people` field is inaccessible and the `Line` class is unmodifiable
- **Swapping the `Line` objects themselves:** I have tried swapping their internal addresses but all I can change is newly created pointers to the objects, not the original variables
- **Subclassing the `Line` class:** I have tried, but it doesn't help because I can't access the `people` field or the `=` operator.

Comment: `void swap(Line& other);` is just the prototype. they might have wanted **you** to implement the function

Comment: it looks to me as if they were asking you to call `line1.swap(line2)` and [maybe also] implement `Line::swap`,

Comment: And of course Line::swap() can use Line::operator=()

Comment: There was no way to implement `Line::swap` as the `Line` class was unmodifiable. If I subclass it I still have no access to the private field and operator.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Do you really mean _equals operator_ or _assignment operator_?

Comment: Did you ask *them* what you were supposed to implement for this task? There seems to be a lot of confusion about that exact point

Comment: This was online. I couldn't speak to anyone. I wish I could have.

Comment: Something doesn't match. `switch_lines` expects vectors but it's called with classes.

Comment: Sorry that is my bad. `switch_lines` takes in `Line` objects

Comment: *"There was no way to implement `Line::swap` as the Line class was unmodifiable"* - what does that even *mean* ? Does that mean `Line::swap` has *already* been implemented and you cannot change it? Or does that mean you cannot alter the class definition, and rather, must implement `Line::swap` as the actual assignment?  Without *exactly* knowing their expectations, you cannot (and thus we cannot) precisely answer this. Guesses are the best to hope for, and guesses make *lousy* answers on this site. `line1.swap(line2)` seems the answer if they provided `Line::swap`. Otherwise, who knows.

Comment: The marked `unmodifiable code` sections do *not* contain a definition of `Line::swap`, which suggests that you may write such a definition outside those sections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The challenge was to modify the switch_lines method.

Simply call the member function `swap` there:

```
line1.swap(line2);
```

> Swap two objects *without* using an equals operator

If you need to implement `Line::swap`, you can simply `std::swap` each sub object:

```
void Line::swap(Line& other) {
    std::swap(people, other.people);
}
```

Comment: `people` is inaccessible. I can't access the private fields as the given `Line` class was unmodifiable.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees I'm not suggesting you to modify `Line`. I understood that the point of the challenge was to implement `Line::swap`. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Since `Line::swap()` is a member function you **can** access the private members there.

Comment: Yes, I think you may have. The challenge was to modify the `switch_lines` method. Which is why there is a `TODO` there.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees so, call the member function. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have no idea why I'm being downvoted so hard I simply panicked and forgot that I can implement a member function from outside the class definition. You just reminded me I can. You are correct. I completely missed that. Thank You, and I'm sorry I asked this question I feel like a fool

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees There must be a reason, that they declared the `Line::swap()` method. The first thing I thought was, that this function is just waiting there to be implemented.

Comment: @user2079303 Your assumption about the likely behaviour of `swap` seems reasonable.  **But**, in the context of an interview question I'd be wary of assumptions made about unseen code.